# Single model for storing django application-wide options

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a set of top-level configuration data fields that I want to be able to set within django admin for each deployment of my django app.  I only want one set of these.

Example fields: site_logo, contact_person, address, facebook_url, twitter_url

The problem is that Django Admin is geared towards tables (lists) of models, so its not a good fit for this type of singular configuration model. I really only want one of these models to exist for the whole site, and to be able to click into it from admin and edit the various fields.

It seems i've come across a 3rd party app in the past to accomplish this but can't find it anywhere.  Part of the problem is I'm finding it difficult to find the right words to google. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [django-values](http://code.google.com/p/django-values/) will do what you're looking for.

Other possible contenders:

- http://github.com/sciyoshi/django-dbsettings (doesn't look maintained)
- http://github.com/jqb/django-settings

Comment: Hmmm.  Is there anything not 5 years old and unmaintained? Was django even at 1.0 in 2007?

Comment: Another thing, my user's will be using admin to edit the rest of the site... django-values doesn't appear to integrate with admin.

Comment: Well, here's one that's 4 years old: https://github.com/sciyoshi/django-dbsettings. It looks like for the most part neither are maintained, though.

Comment: It looks like this one *is* maintained, although I don't know if it integrates with the admin: https://github.com/jqb/django-settings

Comment: Django-settings does provide an admin interface. Its in pypi, so its pip-installable. Its basic, but should do the job.  livesettings, recommended by PhoebeB, looks like more robust option, but is more complexity than i need for now.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [django-livesettings](https://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-livesettings/src) it sounds like it might fit.

Answer (score 1):

Not that i have used it, but i have heard good things about [django-constance](https://github.com/comoga/django-constance/).

And there are even some more options listed in the [Configuration-Grid](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/configuration/) on Django Packages.

Comment: I like this one! I'm going to check it out. Thanks for pointing it out, and for the django-packages link.